# Multiple charts on same page using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to find an example of using multiple charts on same page. Basically I have to show each chart for a person and there performance. I looked at google charts but it uses "id" which has to be unique. I have to use ng-repeat to draw the charts. Can anyone let me know an example of it or how to approach it. I need to draw line charts. I have already tried out google charts, nvd3 etc but having hard time getting them to work. Let me know 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-attr-id={{'i' + person.id}}` to assign unique id in `ng-repeat`, or even use `ng-attr-id={{'i' + $index}}`

Note: id attribute cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jqwidget](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) for chart and line graph . here is a [demo link](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxangular/index.htm#demos/jqxangular/chart.htm) . you can simply use ng-repeat with different data and chart setting provided . I think it may not be that hard working with jqwidget charts . Try and i can help if you need any.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

1. Download ng-google-chart.js from https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/blob/development/ng-google-chart.js and give reference in html page

   `<script src="ng-google-chart.js"></script>`

   and add other references also like

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add it's module in angular app

   ```
   var app = angular.module('appname', ['googlechart']).value('googleChartApiConfig', {
   version: '1',
   optionalSettings: {
       packages: ['corechart'],
       language: 'ja'
   }
   ```

   });
3. Get/assign data like

   ```
   app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $sce, $window) {
       $scope.charts = [{
       "type": "ColumnChart",
       "displayed": false,
       "cssStyle": "height:150px;width: 150px",
       "data": {
           "cols": [{
               "label": "Product",
               "type": "string"
           }, {
               "label": "Agent",
               "type": "number"
           }, {
               "label": "Walkin",
               "type": "number"
           }],
           "rows": [{
               "c": [{
                   "v": ""

               }, {
                   "v": 0
               }, {
                   "v": '#000'
               }]
           }, {
               "c": [{
                   "v": " "
               }, {
                   "v": 10
               }, {
                   "v": '#3366CC'
               }]
           }, {
               "c": [{
                   "v": ""
               }, {
                   "v": 20
               }, {
                   "v": '#3366CC'
               }]
           }]
       },
       "options": {
           //"title": "Product wise sales for each customer",
           "isStacked": "false",
           //"fill": 20,
           //"is3D": false,
           "bar": { groupWidth: '90%' },
           "legend": { position: 'none' },
           //"colors": ["#28a6a8", "rgb(124, 124, 172)", "rgb(0, 227, 253)", "rgb(0, 206, 230)", "rgb(26, 110, 112)"],
           "animation": {
               "startup": true,
               "duration": 2000,
               "easing": "inAndOut"
           },
           'tooltip': {
               trigger: 'none'
           },
           //"displayExactValues": false,

       }
   }, {
       "type": "ColumnChart",
       "displayed": false,
       "cssStyle": "height:150px;width: 150px",
       "data": {
           "cols": [{
               "label": "Product",
               "type": "string"
           }, {
               "label": "Agent",
               "type": "number"
           }, {
               "label": "Walkin",
               "type": "number"
           }],
           "rows": [{
               "c": [{
                   "v": ""

               }, {
                   "v": 10
               }, {
                   "v": '#000'
               }]
           }, {
               "c": [{
                   "v": " "
               }, {
                   "v": 20
               }, {
                   "v": '#3366CC'
               }]
           }, {
               "c": [{
                   "v": ""
               }, {
                   "v": 40
               }, {
                   "v": '#3366CC'
               }]
           }]
       },
       "options": {
           //"title": "Product wise sales for each customer",
           "isStacked": "false",
           //"fill": 20,
           //"is3D": false,
           "bar": { groupWidth: '90%' },
           "legend": { position: 'none' },
           //"colors": ["#28a6a8", "rgb(124, 124, 172)", "rgb(0, 227, 253)", "rgb(0, 206, 230)", "rgb(26, 110, 112)"],
           "animation": {
               "startup": true,
               "duration": 2000,
               "easing": "inAndOut"
           },
           'tooltip': {
               trigger: 'none'
           },
           //"displayExactValues": false,

       }
      }];
   }
   ```
4. Loop data on html as:

   ```
   <body ng-app="appname" ng-cloak="" ng-controller="appController">
       <div dir="rtl" ng-repeat="_chart in charts" google-chart chart="_chart" style="{{_chart.cssStyle}}" ></div>
   </body>
   ```
5. You will get result like[image]